# Auto Reconnect When Using StreamingSubscriptionConnection in EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I've created a small app that watches an inbox using the EWS managed dll.

When I create the `StreamingSubscriptionConnection` I pass in a 1 minute disconnect.

Then in the on disconnect event handler, I sleep for 45 seconds and reconnect.

If anything is sent to the inbox in the 45 second sleep period, it originally appeared as if it woke up and fired the `NotificationEventDelegate` properly.  However after some testing it appears to fire it multiple times for the same email when more than one email arrives.

If I do not sleep then I don't have this problem.  So my questions are, why would the `NotificationEventDelegate` not function properly on reconnect, and is there a problem with immediately reconnecting?

my code is as follows,

```
private MailDirectorServer()
{
    _isRunning = false;

    ExchangeService _service = new ExchangeService()
    {
        Credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password),
        Url = new Uri(uriAddress)
    };

    _connection = 
        new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(_service, 1);

    // set up subscriptions here.
    _connection.OnNotificationEvent +=
                new StreamingSubscriptionConnection.NotificationEventDelegate(OnNewMail);

    _connection.OnDisconnect +=
        new StreamingSubscriptionConnection.SubscriptionErrorDelegate(OnDisconnect);

    _connection.Open();
    _isRunning = true;
}

private void OnDisconnect(object sender, SubscriptionErrorEventArgs args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (_isRunning)
        {
            //_logger.Debug("Sleeping for 45 seconds");
            //Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 45));
            _connection.Open();
            _logger.Info("Connection Re Opened");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.Info("Closing Down");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `Sleep` call - just immediately reconnect (`connection.Open`). See [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6490642/175679). Microsoft also [recommends this process of automatic reconnect in their forums](https://web.archive.org/web/20120702212534/http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/159/t/14645.aspx).

I would also increase the disconnect interval to **30 minutes** to avoid constant opening and closing of the connection. With a one minute disconnect, you may as well be using [Pull Subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa579617%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx).

You should also handle the [`OnSubscriptionError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.streamingsubscriptionconnection.onsubscriptionerror%28v=exchg.80%29) to capture when there are errors with your streaming subscription.

Comment: very cool, thanks for your help!  I do handle the OnSubscriptionError, and occasionally get "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: The specified subscription was not found." Ever heard of such a thing?

Comment: office365 link given above is dead now.

Comment: @HimalayaGarg- [wayback FTW](https://web.archive.org/web/20120702212534/http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/159/t/14645.aspx)